# Take screenshot from videos and put them into Canvas and JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, screenshot

I'm trying to get all the videos from the DOM (quite a few), take a screenshot for each video and put each of them into a different canvas. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f21xxuw9/) here

This is my attempt but it gives this error:

---

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined

---

Any idea how I can solve the issue?

```
  var videoArray = [];
  var canvasArray = [];
  var c = jQuery('<canvas/>',{'width':373.64,'height':227.88}); //set canvas

  jQuery('body').append(c); //append canvas to body

  // push each video into an array
  jQuery('video').each(function(){
      videoArray.push(this);
  });

  //push each canvas into an array
  jQuery('canvas').each(function(){
        canvasArray.push(this);

  });
    //for each video in the array, take a snapshot of the video at position i and draw it
    for(var i = 0; i < videoArray.length; i++){
        canvasArray[i].getContext("2d").drawImage(videoArray[i], 0, 0, 300,200);   

    }
```

Comment: can you include your html markup ?

Comment: @Raghvendra Kumar sure I uploaded a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f21xxuw9/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after some more working I did find a solution. In my code I'm creating a variable c and creating a canvas in it. What I do next is to put this canvas into the body but I put it once. Then I proceed to draw the images all in the same canvas. The new solution is to create a canvas for each video. This is the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f21xxuw9/1/). This is the code of interest.

```
 var videoArray = [];
 var canvasArray = [];
 var c = jQuery('<canvas/>', {
    'width': 373.64,
    'height': 227.88
 }); //set canvas

 //insert a canvas in each div
 jQuery('.wrapper').each(function(){
     jQuery('<canvas/>', {
        'width': 373.64,
        'height': 227.88
     }).appendTo('.wrapper');//append canvas to body
 });


 // push each video into an array
 jQuery('video').each(function() {
     videoArray.push(this);
 });

 //push each canvas into an array
 jQuery('canvas').each(function() {
     canvasArray.push(this);

 });
 //for each video in the array, take a snapshot of the video at position i and draw it
 for (var i = 0; i < videoArray.length; i++) {
     canvasArray[i].getContext("2d").drawImage(videoArray[i], 0, 0, 300, 200);

 }
```